# Pass internet traffic outside of OpenVPN tunnel

Tags: linux, openvpn, gateway, routes

I'm currently using OpenVPN just for external access(my computer are inside a NAT). By default, OpenVPN pass all internet traffic inside OpenVPN and I don't want it, I'll just use VPN for port forwarding.

How I can pass all the internet traffic outside OpenVPN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In very general terms (since OpenVPN can be somewhat of a maze), you want to specify "interesting traffic" for the VPN as a gateway. All else should be pointed elsewhere. If all is going through the VPN, which is probably not soooooo bad, it is likely following a 0.0.0.0 (default route) path. Try to seclude your application/route traffic limited to the OpenVPN gateway path and see if it makes a difference. Conversely, if that is too much manual specification, see if you can specify your Internet traffic to your current ISP gateway or what-have-you, but define certain applications to go only through the specific OpenVPN gateway.

Sorry, this does not do the work for you, but it may expose the nature of your obstacle.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `redirect-gateway...` from your client config or from the options your server pushes to your clients.